# API or library to obtain a mirror of a link

Tags: library, api

I am looking for an API or library to obtain a mirror of a link.

E.g., if I give `http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm` as input, it should return something like `https://web.archive.org/web/20170508020506/http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm` or `http://archive.is/ZEqSG`.

Any operating system, price, programming language or license is fine. I have a preference for Microsoft Windows and python if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [internet archive api](https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php)?

you have to send the send the request `http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=example.com`, and then check the json reply for `data.archived_snapshots.closest.url`